# How to pass struct to offload in Xeon Phi

Tags: c, openmp, xeon-phi

I have a `struct A` with a few `int` and one `int *` member. How can I use this in offload?

I probably can't do `#pragma offload target(mic: 0) inout(A){}`..., but what about

`#pragma offload target(mic: 0) in(A->firstInt, A->secondInt) inout(A->intPointer:length(A->firstInt*A->secondInt)){}`

but I when I tried this I got `error: invalid entity for this variable list in offload clause` in response when compiling

Comment: From what I found about `#pragma offload`, [you'd better tell us what you're trying to do as there may be a better solution](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I'm drawing the Mandelbrot's series and I need to parallelize the drawing loop. From what I gathered, I can't pass the struct because the `A->*member* ` is solved during compile time

Comment: "can't pass the struct (where?) because the A->*member*..." doesn't tell me much, if anything. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask There are no telepaths here, don't assume we know anything about your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt fails because the structure is not bitwise copyable. In fact, it is not allowed to transfer a structure that contains pointers. With the second approach, the compiler cannot match the member variables since `A` is not available on the accelerator. You can solve the problem by extracting the members beforehand and use individual variables instead.

```
struct S {
   int firstInt;
   int secondInt;
   int *intPointer;
};
```

Assuming you have an instance `A` of the structure above, you can do the following.

```
int first = A.firstInt;
int second = A.secondInt;
int *pointer = A.intPointer;
```

Afterwards, you can use the individual variables inside of the offload region.

```
#pragma offload target(mic: 0) in(first, second) 
                               inout(pointer:length(first*second))
{
   /* Use individual variables here. */
}
```

Make sure to allocate memory on the device before copying the data referred by `pointer`.

Alternatively, you can exclude the pointer from your structure and pass it as a separate variable. This way you can copy the entire structure (which is now bitwise copyable) and the pointer individually.

```
#pragma offload target(mic: 0) in(A) inout(pointer:length(A.first*A.second))
```